# If the web app is already installed, will Chrome prompt web app install banner again

Tags: service-worker, progressive-web-apps, manifest.json

Am trying to make my react a PWA. As part of the process I have made the required changes to make chrome prompt the user to install a shortcut to my web app. If someone can answer these questions, that would be of immense help

Lets say the user has installed the web app. Closes the browser. Reopens the  browser at a later time revisits the url, will chrome show the banner again? Does it know that the banner was installed last time?

To verify this, I enabled "Bypass user engagement check" flag in chrome. This results in Chrome showing me the banner all the time, every time (on refresh, subsequent visits, even if the banner is already installed etc). If I disable this flag, the banner shows up the first time I visit the page, but am not sure when it would show up again

Appreciate any help

Thanks
K

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, Chrome will not show the install/add to home screen banner if the user has already done that. If the user removes the app, Chrome may show the banner again. What I mean by ***may*** is that Chrome has some criteria for showing the banner and that has to be met.

You can also track which users get the banner and when by listening for the ***beforeinstallprompt*** event.

Some code samples showing different techniques: https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/app-install-banner/

Comment: I verified this behaviour by going to Chrome->Site Settings-> deleting all the cookies. Once the banner is dismissed Chrome knows not to prompt the banner again. Thanks